# What topics do I need to study electromagnetism on the quantum scale?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, soft-question, education

1. What topics do I need to study (in order) so that I can study electromagnetics on the quantum scale?
2. What is the name of the discipline studying electromagnetism on the quantum scale?
3. Do I need to know nuclear physics?

Comment: Seems you're looking for [Quantum electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) (usually abbreviated as QED).

Comment: AS well as the link Kyle gave you, see the [Quantization of the electromagnetic field Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantization_of_the_electromagnetic_field) for a brief "flavour" of the quantum field. That article is essentially Dirac's legacy and is the "field" side of the topic "quantum optics". Lagrangian mechanics is also a must for making the "quantum optics" / Dirac legacy, which grounded on Hamiltonian mechanics, fully relativistic. History topics IMO are helpful to make the "quantization procedures" seem less arcane.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from scratch I would propose an order of topics to study as follows:

- Kinematics (motion)
- Dynamics (forces)
- Rotational kinematics and dynamics
- Collisions (momentum and impulse)
- Vibrations and waves
- Thermodynamics
- Electricity (DC)
- Electricity (AC)
- Magnetic fields and forces
- Electromagnetic waves
- Light (optics, photons)
- Quantum mechanics

Nuclear physics and all about atoms and molecules are good topics to continue with from here. But not necessary to get the hang of electromagnetism.

Get a book like University Physics by Young & Freedman. It is pedagogical gold for an eager physics student.